# What's the content of Python coverage data files?

Tags: python, code-coverage

How is the content of one `.coverage` or multiple `.coverage.*` data files of Python `coverage v4.5.1` ([rtd](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.5.1a/) / [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/coverage/)) structured and how does it look like in detail for all possible invocation and file structure use cases?

Comment: Which tool and Python version do you have in mind?

Comment: I added the tool version in the question. Makes the Python version any difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.coverage` data files are in a private format that isn't meant to be read directly.  It will change in the future.  What use do you have in mind?

Comment: I thought about how coverage data could help in implementing Test Impact Analysis. Would be interesting if coverage data contains semantical information...

Comment: You can use this API: http://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.5.1a/api_coveragedata.html

Comment: ...in case someone is interested in [test impact analysis in python](https://github.com/fkromer/python-tia)

Comment: You should ask about your real questions, rather than details like file formats.  I'm working toward implementing [Who Tests What](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues/170).  I think it might be useful for you.

Comment: Enlighting [blog post](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201612/who_tests_what.html). Would be great if `coverage.py` could provide as granular semantic coverage as possible. ATM I am not interested in meta data for visualization (lines, etc.).

Comment: I'm currently working on shifting the data storage to SQLite so we can accommodate the needs of who-tests-what.  I don't know what you have in mind by "as granular semantic coverage as possible."

Comment: Great. According the issue/blog SQLite is no performance bottleneck, right? I mean coverage which maps a single test to `functions`, `classes`, `class methods`, `instance methods`, `static methods`, `properties`, etc. of the production code. The comments get's off-topic w.r.t. this question I guess. I'll probably join the discussion in the issue or blog post...

Comment: Drop me an email, and we can continue the discussion :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll do so. Probably the [README of `python-tia`](https://github.com/fkromer/python-tia/blob/master/README.md) will be more up-to-date in the meanwhile as well...

Comment: ...in the beginning getting file scope coverage data (which production code files have been covered) via [`coverage.CoverageData.measured_files()`](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.5.1a/api_coveragedata.html#the-coveragedata-class) should be sufficient.